# Not able to install JBoss on Eclipse Helios from Eclipse market place

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-marketplace

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

> Software being installed: JBoss Runtime Seam Detector 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.seam.detector.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final)
>
> Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
>
> Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>
> Debug Core 3.7.1.v20111129-2031 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.1.v20111129-2031)
>
> Debug Core 3.6.0.v20100519 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.6.0.v20100519)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
>
> To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110218-0812]
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
>
> To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi)
>
> To: org.eclipse.debug.core [3.6.0.v20100519]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: JBoss Runtime Seam Detector 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.seam.detector 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final)
>
> To: bundle org.jboss.tools.seam.core 0.0.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: JBoss Runtime Seam Detector 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.seam.detector.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final)
>
> To: org.jboss.tools.runtime.seam.detector [1.3.0.v20130112-0541-H121-Final]
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Seam Tools 3.3.0.v20130112-0336-H148-Final (org.jboss.tools.seam.core 3.3.0.v20130112-0336-H148-Final)
>
> To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.0

Comment: Looks like Helios is too old for the software you are trying to install.

Comment: Thanks grep, let me update my eclipse with the latest version first.

Comment: Thanks greg, i updated my eclipse to neon 4.6.1 version and downloaded the jboss 7.1.1 version. Now there is no dependencies issues coming, jboss is started now.

Comment: What is the question?